# Entity Framework error: SqlException: Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'SiteCategory' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-8

I have three tables `Tags`, `TagCategories` and `SiteCategory`.

`TagCategories` has two columns; one is the index of `Tags` and the other is the index from `SiteCategory`; that means that between `Tags` and `SiteCategory`, there is a many-to-many relationship.

When I do scaffold for my database in the .NET Core 8 projects the scaffold builds two models one for `Tags` and the other for `SiteCategory` and the model builder is:

Tag

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Tag>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.Indx);

            entity.Property(e => e.Tag1)
                .HasMaxLength(50)
                .HasColumnName("Tag");

            entity.HasMany(d => d.Categories).WithMany(p => p.Tags)
                .UsingEntity<Dictionary<string, object>>(
                    "TagCategory",
                    r => r.HasOne<SiteCategory>().WithMany()
                        .HasForeignKey("CategoryId")
                        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                        .HasConstraintName("FK_TagCategories_SiteCategory"),
                    l => l.HasOne<Tag>().WithMany()
                        .HasForeignKey("TagId")
                        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                        .HasConstraintName("FK_TagCategories_Tags"),
                    j =>
                    {
                        j.HasKey("TagId", "CategoryId");
                        j.ToTable("TagCategories");
                        j.IndexerProperty<int>("TagId").HasColumnName("TagID");
                        j.IndexerProperty<int>("CategoryId").HasColumnName("CategoryID");
                    });
        });
```

SiteCategory :

```
modelBuilder.Entity<SiteCategory>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.Indx);

            entity.ToTable("SiteCategory");

            entity.Property(e => e.Category).HasMaxLength(18);
            entity.Property(e => e.ShowInSystem)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasDefaultValueSql("((1))");
        });
```

I am trying to create a new tag and add and I have the `SiteCategory` index, so I want to add it to the `TagCategories` table.

My function:

```
public bool addTagAndTagCategory(Tag tag, int? categoryID)
{
        try
        {
            var siteCat = db.SiteCategories.Where(cat => cat.Indx == categoryID).FirstOrDefault();
            siteCat.Tags.Add(tag);
            db.Add(tag);
            //var TagCategory = new Dictionary<string, object>
            //    {
            //        { "TagId", tag.Indx },
            //        { "CategoryId", siteCat.Indx }
            //    };
            //db.Attach(TagCategory);
            db.SaveChanges();
            var res = tag.Indx != 0 ? true : false;
            return res;
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
}
```

I get this error:

> SqlException: Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'SiteCategory' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF

Comment: problem solved, the problem was that i have to add the tag first save the db context to get an indx for the tag and then update it,

Comment: That's a *critical* bug which suggest the application is misusing EF Core. You tried to do what SaveChanges would do for you automatically. A DbContext is a multi-entity Unit-of-Work which detects changes to *all* the objects it tracks. You should only call `SaveChanges` once at the very end of the business transaction/Unit-of-Work/API action, to persist all changes at once. When that happens, generated IDs are retrieved and set in the objects that need them

Comment: That means `addTagAndTagCategory` could easily perform 43 DELETEs and 67 UPDATEs, not just add a new tag.